# BluetoothChat + TTS

Tags: android, bluetooth, text-to-speech

I am trying to add tts (TextToSpeech) at BluetoothChat project of the android SDK
i want to convert the text received from another device to voice and at same time i can sent the text that will be voice when the anther device received it .

BluetoothChat.java

```
 /**
 * Sends a message.
 * @param message  A string of text to send.
 */
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}

// The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener =
    new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        if(D) Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
        return true;
    }
};

// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the buffer
            String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
            // save the connected device's name
            mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                           + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
        // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the device MAC address
            String address = data.getExtras()
                                 .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
            // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            // Attempt to connect to the device
            mChatService.connect(device);
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
        // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
            setupChat();
        } else {
            // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
            Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.scan:
        // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
        Intent serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
        return true;
    case R.id.discoverable:
        // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
        ensureDiscoverable();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onInit(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

witting the answer 
thank u :)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: All you have to do is call tts.speak when you receive the text :P

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following code.

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(YourActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                tts.speak("", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        });
```